# Crear una Row en data GridView utilizando datos de una base de datos VB

Tags: vb.net

**Crear una row basada en una row de una base de datos**

Asi que miren yo se que probablemente esto es basico, pero JURO haber buscado en internet como hacer esto y no encontrado respuestas.
Basicamente lo que busco, es hacer que mi programa busque en una base de datos por una Row en especifico por su id y despues ser impreso en un datagridview

> (Por ejemplo 'Yo pongo 12321 en buscar y el resultado exacto es
>   impreso como una row en un DataGridView)

Realmente no me puedo explicar mas pues no cuento con el codigo que ya tengo a la mano.

En caso de que te tomes tu tiempo en responder mi duda realmente lo aprecio.

Comment: no te entiendo muy bien, quieres escribir en una celda del datagridview ej "1232" y al dar buscar que te imprima en el resto de la fila la informacion correspondiente a ese producto? asi?

Comment: Si eso es lo que necesito

Comment: debes usar el evento CellEndEdit de tu datagridview, para capturar lo que escribiste  " string codigo_consulta = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();//codigo " con eso has la consulta a la base de datos y por ultimo luego que tengas cada resultado en una variable lo añades a las demas celdas "dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column2"].Value = valor_1;"

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, mi forma favorita es hacerlo desde linq, pero quizás una más básica y sencilla es con un databindingsource.

DataBindingSource tiene la opción filter, y sería tan práctico como escribir algo como esto:

```
filtro = "[NombreColumna] = " & textoaBuscar;
BindingSource.Filter = filtro
```

Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo con muchas opciones:
http://www.recursosvisualbasic.com.ar/htm/vb-net/51-filtrar-datagridview.htm

Espero te sirva.